hibernate keeps searching for tables in all caps
In my Jakarta ee app using JPA Hibernate. I generated my entities based on the persistence window connected to the database. But whenever i call an EntityManager method, i keep getting:
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement [Table "OWNERS" not found (this database is empty); SQL statement: select o1_0.id,o1_0.name,o1_0.password,o1_0.token,o1_0.username from owners o1_0 where o1_0.id=? [42104-220]] [select o1_0.id,o1_0.name,o1_0.password,o1_0.token,o1_0.username from owners o1_0 where o1_0.id=?]

I tried:
@Entity
@Table(name = "owners")
public class Owners {

But it acts like I didn't specify any other table name than OWNERS.

hello, which database are you using ? Try to specify schema on @Table annotation

I'm using a mysql database. as far as i can see the schema is the database name? i've tried entering it. but once again the same error, just not it says Schema "SPOTITUBE" not found. once again in caps while i specified the schema in lowercase.
